# How do I Block Public access while allowing cross-account access in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to enable the block public access toggle, but I have a bucket policy that enables access from a different account. I still want this bucket to have cross-account access while blocking public access. What is the best solution for this? What are the best practices keeping in mind the new settings AWS will implement in April?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the best practices keeping in mind the new settings AWS will implement in April?

The new settings will disable ACLs and block public access by default. This means that, only the bucket policy will be used for checking access. This has been already the best practice for a long time, they're making it the default now.

Blocking public access will not break your cross-account access. If you have the proper policies on your bucket and the cross-account IAM role, you can still access the bucket.